# Reading SD file and extract information about every fragment

Tags: perl

I have a SD file to read. I couldn't upload the whole file. so I gave a snapshot in the image below.

[image: A SD file (Structural data file) that explains the structure of a molecule. 803 and AMH are two molecules. Also, within same molecule there are several fragments. Each fragment is separated by four dollar sign ($$$$).]
This is a SD file (Structural data file) that explains the structure of a molecule. 803 and AMH are two molecules. Also, within same molecule there are several fragments. Each fragment is separated by four dollar sign ($$$$). I am a new to perl as I am a biomedical research student. However, I wrote a script that finds the occurrence of $$$$ and then the occurrence of molecule code (here 803) in line next to it.

```
{
    open (FILE, '<', "try_803.txt");    
    my $ligandcode="803";    
    while (<FILE>) {
        my $nextline = <FILE>;     
        if ( $_=~/\x24\x24\x24\x24/ &&  $nextline=~/$ligandcode/){    
            # do something
        }    
    }    
}
```

This code checks the very first occurrence of $$$$ followed by 803. But, I want it to go further to next occurrence of $$$$ followed by 803. I don't know how many times will this pattern will occur. technically I can't specify the no of fragment before hand. Can you help me improving this code and finding a solution for problem. I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the input record separator to four dolar signs, a newline and 803.

```
local $/ = '$$$$' . "\n803";
```

Then, you can read the whole molecules in a loop:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    my $molecule = $_;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked. But this script is passing whole block in $molecule. And I want to access each row separately in order to perform some other function. Please help

Comment: thanks.But when I use the following code 4th line is printed in chunk 1 however, 5th line is printing in other chunk.    `while (<FILE>){
 my $molecule = $_;
 my @lines=  split(/\n/);
 print $lines[3] , "\n";
}`   I want to specify that every chunk starts with $$$$ and 8033 in next line. So $$$$ becomes 1st line of each chunk and 803 becomes 2nd line. please help

Comment: @shpr: Why do you need to have the dollars and the number in the array? And if you really need them (which I doubt), you can `unshift @lines, '$$$$', 803;` after splitting.

Comment: thanks. And yes I dont need $$$$ and 803 rather i need this block    **10 11  0  0  0  0            999 V2000        
   -1.7992   -1.7457    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0          
   -2.5137   -1.3332    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0          
   ** but while these reading lines, if I use $lines[3] it is reading 4th line in chunk 1 and third line in following chunks. please help